# Server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this question has been asked a bunch of times but I'm not finding any answer that helps.

So I have two pages, index.php and refer.php. I put a rule into my httpd.conf that used mod_rewrite to get rid of the .php extension when a user goes to the page. Refer.php worked fine to show up as just *refer*, but trying to go to index.php gives me a Forbidden error.

Error log shows this:

```
AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive.
```

Here's the relevant part of my httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The file index.php exists, of course. Any help?

Edit:

The url is just the root url - like domain.com. It should access index.php, which it did fine before I did the mod_rewrite. So I expect the index page to come up, which it doesn't because of the errors that I described above. .htaccess file is just all defaults except for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: What are the contents of the .htaccess files.  https://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/  What URL are you placing in the browser URL field, and what do you expect to occur.

Comment: @BradleyRoss Just edited the original question to answer your questions.

Comment: @anubhava Already have that: <IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

Comment: Does `http://example.com/index.php` work for you?